# Need Help on Calculate Percentage of Failure of All Columns in Very Large MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, r

I'm having trouble to calculate percentage of failure of every column for my very large MySQL table. Here is an example on how the small table will look like:

Assuming TABLE1 has 5 columns and 100 rows,
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST TABLE1 (id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, col1 DOUBLE NOT NULL, col2 DOUBLE NOT NULL, col3 NOT DOUBLE NULL, col4 NOT DOUBLE NULL);`

Each column from "col1" to "col4" having its own upper and lower limits and I need to find what is the percentage of failure for "col1" to "col4". Here is the example on how I run my calculation now.

*Calculate total number of rows and group by column "id"*
`SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY id;`

*Calculate total number of rows where col1,col2,col3,col4 meets all the limits and group by column "id"*
`SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 WHERE (col1 BETWEEN 0 AND 10) AND (col2 BETWEEN 10 AND 20) AND (col3 BETWEEN 20 AND 30) AND (col3 BETWEEN 30 AND 40) GROUP BY id;`

*Calculate total number of rows that not meet col1 limit*
`SELECT id, COUNT(col1) FROM TABLE1 WHERE (col1 NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 10) GROUP BY id;`

*Calculate total number of rows that meet col1 limit but not meet col2 limit, group by "id"*
`SELECT id, COUNT(col2) FROM TABLE1 WHERE (col1 BETWEEN 0 AND 10) AND (col2 NOT BETWEEN 10 AND 20) GROUP BY id;`

*Calculate total number of rows that meet col1,col2 limit but not meet col3 limit, group by "id"*
`SELECT id, COUNT(col3) FROM TABLE1 WHERE (col1 BETWEEN 0 AND 10) AND (col2 BETWEEN 10 AND 20) AND (col3 NOT BETWEEN 20 AND 30) GROUP BY id;`

*Calculate total number of rows that meet col1,col2,col3 limit but not meet col4 limit, group by "id"*
`SELECT id, COUNT(col4) FROM TABLE1 WHERE (col1 BETWEEN 0 AND 10) AND (col2 BETWEEN 10 AND 20) AND (col3 BETWEEN 20 AND 30) AND (col3 NOT BETWEEN 30 AND 40) GROUP BY id;`

I've written an R script to execute the above 5 queries and combine the result under one data frame. Here is example of the output after processed by R:
`id,total_no_rows,yield,col1,col2,col3,col4`
`CATEGORY1,25,80%,2%,8%,4%,6%,0%`
`CATEGORY2,25,70%,6%,14%,2%,6%,2%`
`CATEGORY3,25,90%,5%,0%,5%,0%,0%`
`CATEGORY4,25,65%,20%,2.5%,2.5%,5%,5%`

Now using this method i can get the result pretty quick for small table. However if the table become very large, say 1000 columns and 1 million of rows, the time to complete the calculation is ~ 2 hours, which is extremely long.

Is there anyway i can speed up the calculation?

1. I've tried indexing but apparently MySQL cannot index 1000 columns.
2. Tried simultaneous query (10 queries at one time) but no much improvement. (I'm using InnoDB by the way)
3. I've read some of the posts where users suggests to split the table into smaller chunks to speed up the queries execution. However, my raw data is poorly managed (long story) and all the data dumped into one big text file. So dividing the raw data in smaller chunk will be a challenge.

Please let me know if you have any alternative method to approach this kind of problem.

Edit:
Looks like the the proposal from Mani did save a lot of time to get the result. However the time to complete the query still takes around 10 minutes for very large table (Thousands of column and millions of rows). Is there any way to further improve the query time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case and find all possible scenario in a single select hit. It will reduce your time.

example

```
select id, count(*), 
sum(case when col1 between 0 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) col1_yes,
sum(case when (col1 not between 0 and 10) and (col2 between 0 and 10) then 1 
else 0 end) col1no_col2yes 
from table 
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try out and I'll let you know the result.

Comment: Thanks! Its working! Is there anyway to speed up the process for this single query? It still takes more than 30 sec to complete the query.